# How to use appendTo code when want to Copy same code to multiple divs?

Tags: jquery

I have a code and when I am cloning that code then fewer values are found to be reset on its own.It worked with appendTo() function but I want to use appendTo for multiple divs
For example:

```
<div id="allocationId"><select><option value="">Select</option><option value="A" selected>A</option></div>
<div id="modalDiv"></div>
<div id="tmpDiv"></div>
```

I want to append code defined inside allocationId to modalDiv and tmpDiv
Code that doesn't work:

```
$('#allocationId').find('select').clone().appendTo('#tmpDiv')
//Another Code that don't works  
$('#allocationId').find('select').appendTo('#tmpDiv #modalDiv')
//Code that works but its just for only one div  
$('#allocationId').find('select').appendTo('#tmpDiv ')
```

Please provide helpful suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var select = $('#allocationId').find('select');
select.clone().appendTo('#tmpDiv,#modalDiv');
```

Also you are missing a closing `</select>` tag

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/Yf8Rn/)